# Collection runs in Postman, and not in Newman - Invalid URI error

Tags: json, postman, newman

I have a collection that runs in Postman, and not in Newman.

This is the error - 
newman -c Products.postman_collection.json -e Products.postman_environment.json

```
Iteration 1 of 1
RequestError: [d395a91e-4220-4c2c-81bd-cff20cac63b8] 'Product Detail' terminated. Complete error: 
Error: Invalid URI "http:///%7B%7BbaseUrl%7D%7D/shop/%7B%7BapiVer%7D%7D/products/samsung-ypk3?client_id=%7B%7BclientId%7D%7D"
    at Request.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/request/request.js:288:31)
    at new Request (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/request/request.js:142:8)
    at request (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/request/index.js:55:10)
    at Object.jsface.Class._execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/newman/src/runners/RequestRunner.js:181:26)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/newman/src/runners/RequestRunner.js:87:20)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:224:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:198:5)
RequestError: [f909ee1b-334a-40ed-94ec-4398c12bd442] 'Product Images' terminated. Complete error: 
Error: Invalid URI "http:///%7B%7BbaseUrl%7D%7D/shop/%7B%7BapiVer%7D%7D/products/samsung-ypk3/images?client_id=%7B%7BclientId%7D%7D"
    at Request.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/request/request.js:288:31)
    at new Request (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/request/request.js:142:8)
    at request (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/newman/node_modules/request/index.js:55:10)
    at Object.jsface.Class._execute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/newman/src/runners/RequestRunner.js:181:26)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/newman/src/runners/RequestRunner.js:222:20)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:224:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:198:5)
```

The URI in Postman looks like this -

```
http://{{baseUrl}}/{{apiType}}/{{apiVer}}/products/{{productId}}?client_id={{clientId}}
```

When I open the collection's JSON file, this is what that the URI looks like -

```
"url": "http://{{baseUrl}}/{{apiType}}/{{apiVer}}/products/{{productId}}?client_id={{clientId}}"
```

Any ideas on what could be causing the Invalid URI error?

Updated the newman invocation to the following -

```
newman -c Products.postman_collection.json -e globals.postman_globals.json -e Products.postman_environment.json
```

where the first env var file is the Postman globals, and the second env var file is the collection specific env vars. Still seeing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Had to pass the globals file with a -g option. So the final command looks like -

```
newman -c Products.postman_collection.json -g globals.postman_globals.json -e Products.postman_environment.json
```